# converting an explicit formula into a generating series

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials

> Let $f_n = p_1(n) \lambda_1^n + p_2(n)\lambda_2^n + \cdots + p_s(n) \lambda_s^n$ for all $n\geq N$, where $p_i(n)$ is a polynomial of degree strictly less than $d_i$ and the $\lambda_i$ are distinct nonzero complex numbers for $1\leq i\leq s.$ Let $C(x) = (1-\lambda_1x)^{d_1}\cdots (1-\lambda_s x)^{d_s}.$ Show that $F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n x^n = A(x) + \dfrac{B(x)}{C(x)},$ where $B(x)$ and $A(x)$ are polynomials and $\deg B(x) < \deg C(x)$ and $\deg A(x) < N.$

The contribution of the inverse root $\lambda_i$ to the coefficient of $x^n, $ or $f_n,$ is clearly $p_i(n)\lambda_i^n$. I also know that $\dfrac{A}{(1-\lambda_i)^j} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A\cdot {n+j-1\choose j-1} \lambda_i^n x^n$ and that since $\{1,(n+1),\cdots, {n+j-1\choose j-1}\}$ forms a basis for the vector space of polynomials of degree less than $j,$ we can find constants $a_{i,j}$ for each $p_i(n)$ so that $p_i(n) = a_{i,1} +a_{i,2} {n+1\choose 1} + \cdots + a_{i,d_i} {n+d_i-1\choose d_i-1}.$ If I multiply by $\lambda_i^n x^n$ and sum over all the possible values of $n,$ I get something like \begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_i(n)\lambda_i^n x^n &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^{d_i} a_{i,j} {n+j-1\choose j-1} \lambda_i^n x^n\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{d_i} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{i,j}{n+j-1\choose j-1}\lambda_i^n x^n = \sum_{j=1}^{d_i} \dfrac{a_{i,j}}{(1-\lambda_ix)^j}\end{align}   However, I'm not sure how to find $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ from this.

> Edit: From a comment below, I've decided to do the following:
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty g_nx^n  &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} g_nx^n + \sum_{n=N}^\infty g_n x^n \\
> &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sum_{i=1}^s \sum_{j=1}^{d_i} b_{i,j} {n+j-1\choose j-1}\lambda_i^n)x^n - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (\sum_{i=1}^s \sum_{j=1}^{d_i} b_{i,j} {n+j-1\choose j-1}\lambda_i^n)x^n + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} g_nx^n.
> \end{align}
> Let $A(x) = - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (\sum_{i=1}^s \sum_{j=1}^{d_i} b_{i,j} {n+j-1\choose j-1}\lambda_i^n)x^n + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} g_nx^n.$ Note that $A(x)$ has degree at most $N-1$, since the maximum power of $x$ is $N-1.$ Then $F(x)-A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sum_{i=1}^s \sum_{j=1}^{d_i} b_{i,j} {n+j-1\choose j-1}\lambda_i^n)x^n = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^s\sum_{j=1}^{d_i} \dfrac{b_{i,j}}{(1-\lambda_i x)^j},\\$ and using partial fractions, we find that there is a unique $B(x)$ with $\deg B(x) < \deg C(x)$ so that $\dfrac{B(x)}{C(x)} = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^s\sum_{j=1}^{d_i} \dfrac{b_{i,j}}{(1-\lambda_i x)^j}.$

Comment: Remember, the equation $f_n=p_1(n)\lambda_1^n+\dots$ only holds for $n\ge N$. So to compute $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_nx^n$, you should split into two parts, $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}$ and $\sum_{n=N}^\infty$. The second sum can be solved using almost the same method you used, and the first will give some random terms which contribute to $A(x)$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I've made some changes to my question based on your input. Let me know what you think!